# Couchbase Join Failed to Return JSON

Tags: join, couchbase

Couchbase – Version 4.1.0-5005

Query Workbench Developer Review – Version 1.0.2

I am working on a process to determine if a Model exists for a Grid.  I start by building the N1QL Statement section (listed below).  This N1QL Statement determines the association of the Grids with the Model.  Prior to generating this N1QL Statement, I ran individual statements to ensure the presented Model Id exist within both document types.

```
select a.model_id
  from inputs as a
       join inputs as b on keys a.model_id
where a.type = 'Model'
  and b.type = 'Grid'
  and a.model_id = 100
```

I modeled the N1QL Statement after the example provided by Couchbase beer-sample (listed below).  In addition, I modified the Couchbase example to mirror the above.

```
select br.name brewery,
       b.name beer,
       b.style style
  from `beer-sample` b 
       join `beer-sample` br on keys b.brewery_id
 where b.type = 'beer'
   and br.type = 'brewery'
   and b.name = '21A IPA'
```

When I execute the Couchbase provided example, I receive a single JSON document.  When I execute my N1QL Statement, it returns no JSON document.  I verified that both types contain at least one JSON document for the model id specified.  The bucket only contains a primary index.  No other indexes exist.

I appreciate any suggestion in resolving this issue.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The primary key (external id) of your Grid documents needs to be the same as the model_id of your Model document.

The N1QL syntax is not joining over a common field. It is joining an expression from the left hand term to the primary key of the right hand term.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  It appears I will not be able to perform the joins based on the bucket setup.  Primary key for both tables are different.

Comment: Ok. Hopefully you can move to a setup using primary keys, especially if you a 1:N relationship.